# Style datepicker on span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

How do I style the `datepicker` on the span only?

If you select the text box, it copies the style with the red font.

I wish to only style the datepicker within the `mydate` span.

```
div.ui-datepicker, .ui-datepicker td{
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

[Change Color on span Datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/ra3e0yeu/)

Comment: What would you like to achieve? `Sa` and `Su` to be red?

Comment: The goal is when I select the text box when that datepicker displays for it to use the default colors.  But the `<span id="mydate" name="mydate" class="datepicker"></span>` to use the modified style with the red font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your id to css

```css
#mydate .ui-datepicker, #mydate .ui-datepicker td{
  font-size: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.  Pretty sure I tired this before but wasn't getting anywhere.  Maybe with all of the other code I had was confusing me.